# Automating migrations for entities in custom modules

Tags: module, entity-framework-core, migration, abp

I've changed my DBMS provider to use CosmosDB in EFCore. There were some changes needed for the built-in entities to address etag concurrency, partition keys, etc. but once those were done this worked well.
We've been creating several different modules off the module template, and of course those modules have their EFCore projects. We have some custom code in the application's DB Migrator project which will create the necessary Cosmos containers if they don't exist (based on the configuration of the entities in the context). This process does not pickup the entities in the custom modules, however. We'd like to have the migrator project create all the necessary containers - discover the entities in the custom modules - in one place.
Before going too far down the road of creating something custom I wanted to see if there is a recommended or existing way to handle this that I've just missed in the docs. You could even take Cosmos out of the equation and think of this as migrations for relational databases; I'm interested in the suggested way to hook into the migration infrastructure for entities defined and configured in modules we've created.

We've tried adding a DependsOn entry to the application's EFCore module to referring to the EF module in the actual module solution we created. This works great at runtime  and everything appears to be wired up properly.
We tried adding a DependsOn entry in the migrator module as well though that did not seem to change the behavior for what is picked up when the migrator is run.

Comment: As I know EF Core CosmosDB provider do not supports migrations

Comment: Correct, and from the traditional relational db standpoint they would not be relevant - there isn't any schema to make changes to as there would be in mssql for instance. However, Cosmos does require that the container to which you are writing exist prior to attempting to use it, so although not technically a migration, we do this within the migrator service to make sure the target containers for all the entities exist. we can also use the data seeding process to create the initial user account for example. This works fine for the main application, just looking to tie in modules too.

Comment: I figured this out. Using as slight modification to the section on automating the second database schema migration at https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Entity-Framework-Core-Migrations I got it to do what I needed it to do.

Comment: @JoshHulbert Would you write an answer with more details? If you don't think it would be useful to others, you may delete this question.